# Boolean field not in CSV views export

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I have a boolean field (a checkbox) in my user profiles. I have left it with the default settings (1= ticked, 0=unticked).

I have created an CSV export in Views of the user data. All the fields in the user profile work, apart from the boolean value, which is not exported (it just appears as "", for all users). If I look at user profiles however, the box is ticked (or unticked) so the data is there, just not being exported.

How can I get this field to export?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve this - I needed to change the formatter for the field to "Key".

Comment: Hey James, seems to me you should mark this answer as "accepted", no? Are are you trying to hide it from upvoting?